# How to determine primary key of a specific SQL table?

Tags: mysql

I mean not mean by manually reading the output of `show create table...`, but by `select ...` so that the primary key name is output directly as the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
show index from CC_CSR_USER where Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

CC_CSR_USER is a table name. Have a look on the column_name field on the result, you will get that PRIMARY KEY column of the table.

Answer (score 3):

The following query should give you the PKs - just plug in your table_schema and table_name at the bottom of the query.

```
SELECT k.`COLUMN_NAME`
  FROM `information_schema`.`TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` t
  JOIN `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` k
  USING (`CONSTRAINT_NAME`, `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`)
  WHERE t.`CONSTRAINT_TYPE` = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND t.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName'
    AND t.`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName';
```

Comment: Why is the statement so slow?

Comment: Not sure - it shouldn't be. Do you have anything else running?